# CGBitmapContext in MonoTouch throws invalid handle exception

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, cgbitmapcontext

I'm new to MonoTouch and I've recently been converting code from standard C# to MonoTouch compliant code so it can be used within an iPhone application.  I've managed to convert the code, however I've run into a problem with this method which I use to return a bitmap context:

```
private CGBitmapContext ExtractWriteableBitmap( RGBPaletteRecord rgbPalette, double dpi, ChartIndexFile indexFile, RasterChartFile chartFile )
        {
            CGBitmapContext bitmapImage = null;
            TileRecord tile;

            // calc the number of tiles in each plane
            int tileCountX = indexFile.TileIndexRecords.Max(ti => ti.X);
            int tileCountY = indexFile.TileIndexRecords.Max(ti => ti.Y);

            // create the big picture
            int pixelWidth = (tileCountX + 1) * TileRecord.PixelWidth;
            int pixelHeight = (tileCountY + 1) * TileRecord.PixelHight;

            int intDPI = Convert.ToInt32(dpi);

            int bytesPerRow = (int)TileRecord.PixelWidth * 4; // note that bytes per row should 
    //be based on width, not height.

            CGColorSpace colorSpace = CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB();
            CGImageAlphaInfo info = CGImageAlphaInfo.NoneSkipFirst;

            // create the big picture 
            bitmapImage = new CGBitmapContext(System.IntPtr.Zero, pixelWidth, pixelHeight, intDPI, intDPI, colorSpace, info);

            byte[] sourceArray;
            RectangleF sourceRect;

            //copy the tiles into the big picture
            int index = 0;
            foreach (TileIndexRecord tileIndexRecord in indexFile.TileIndexRecords)
            {
                // get the tile record
                tile = chartFile.TileRecords[index];

                // extract the byte array for the given palette
                sourceArray = tile.GetBytes(rgbPalette);

                GCHandle pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(sourceArray, GCHandleType.Pinned);
                IntPtr pointer = pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject();
                //do your stuff
                //pinnedArray.Free();

                CGImage image = new CGImage(pointer);
                sourceRect = new RectangleF(0, 0, TileRecord.PixelWidth, TileRecord.PixelHight); 

                bitmapImage.DrawImage(new RectangleF(0,0,128,128),image);

                // copy the tile image into the big picture
                //bitmapImage.WritePixels(sourceRect, sourceArray, TileRecord.Stride, (tileIndexRecord.X * TileRecord.PixelWidth), (tileIndexRecord.Y * TileRecord.PixelHight));

                // increment the index
                index++;
            }
            return bitmapImage;
        }
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
System.Exception: Invalid handle
  at MonoTouch.CoreGraphics.CGContext..ctor (IntPtr handle, Boolean owns) [0x00022] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/shared/CoreGraphics/CGContext.cs:136
  at MonoTouch.CoreGraphics.CGBitmapContext..ctor (IntPtr data, Int32 width, Int32 height, Int32 bitsPerComponent, Int32 bytesPerRow, MonoTouch.CoreGraphics.CGColorSpace colorSpace, CGImageAlphaInfo bitmapInfo) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Jargoon.Data.Arcs.Loader.ExtractWriteableBitmap (Jargoon.Data.Arcs.Records.RGBPaletteRecord rgbPalette, Double dpi, Jargoon.Data.Arcs.Raschts.ChartIndexFile indexFile, Jargoon.Data.Arcs.Raschts.RasterChartFile chartFile) [0x00079] in /Users/jacknutkins/Desktop/Jargoon/ARCSViewer/ARCSViewer/Loader.cs:569
  at Jargoon.Data.Arcs.Loader.GetHiResImage (Jargoon.Data.Arcs.Records.RGBPaletteRecord rgbPalette) [0x00000] in /Users/jacknutkins/Desktop/Jargoon/ARCSViewer/ARCSViewer/Loader.cs:361
  at ARCSViewer.ARCSViewerViewController.ViewDidLoad () [0x0001c] in /Users/jacknutkins/Desktop/Jargoon/ARCSViewer/ARCSViewer/ARCSViewerViewController.cs:37
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00042] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:29
  at ARCSViewer.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/jacknutkins/Desktop/Jargoon/ARCSViewer/ARCSViewer/Main.cs:17
```

The error occurs at the line:

```
// create the big picture 
            bitmapImage = new CGBitmapContext(System.IntPtr.Zero, pixelWidth, pixelHeight, intDPI, intDPI, colorSpace, info);
```

I'm very new to MonoTouch so try and bear with me if its glaringly obvious but can anyone explain whats going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when you're running out of memory. The (device) console will usually print more information though.

My guess is that you're not freeing the CGBitmapContext you're creating.

Comment: Cheers for the input, I've edited the question with the rest of the stack trace I got, how would I go about freeing the context?  Cheers

Comment: Does the exception occur the first time this code is called, or after several iterations? And which arguments do you pass to the CGBitmapContext constructor (it will fail like this if you try to create a bitmap that is too big for instance)?

Comment: Yeh that was the problem (way too big), I managed to figure it out last night, thanks a lot.